# Snowflake:Most unique field of rows from JSON

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement : To get single_address_object which has unique values in all rows
Example as below data , Country and Region is common in all rows

```
     id , address
     ----------------
    111 , {   "City": "Garner",   "Country": "US",   "County": "Hancock",   "Line1": "490 W 8th St",   "PostalCode": "50438",   "Region": "TX" }
    111 , {   "City": "Colleyville",   "Country": "US",   "County": "Tarrant",   "Line1": "1002 Saddlebrook Dr",   "PostalCode": "76034",   "Region": "TX" }
    111 , {   "City": "Dublin",   "Country": "US",   "County": "Franklin",   "Line1": "545 Metro Pl S Ste 100",   "PostalCode": "43017",   "Region": "TX" }
```

Output

Need new column as below

```
    single_address_object
    ----------------------
    {"Country:"US", "Region":"TX"}
```

Comment: So what have you tried and what specific issue are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if below works for you.

If you are expecting to be dynamic then you need to write a stored procedure to parse column names and build query similar to below using dynamic column names.

```
select case when left(res,2)='{,' then '{'||right(res,len(res)-2) else res end res
from (
    select '{'
        ||
        
          ifnull(case when count(distinct city) = 1 then '"city":"'||max(city)||'"' end ,'')
        || ifnull(case when count(distinct Country) = 1 then ',"Country":"'||max(Country)||'"' end ,'')
        || ifnull(case when count(distinct County) = 1 then ',"County":"'||max(County)||'"' end ,'')
        || ifnull(case when count(distinct Line1) = 1 then ',"Line1":"'||max(Line1)||'"' end ,'')
        || ifnull(case when count(distinct PostalCode) = 1 then ',"PostalCode":"'||max(PostalCode)||'"' end ,'')
        || ifnull(case when count(distinct Region) = 1 then ',"Region":"'||max(Region)||'"' end ,'')
        ||'}'
         res
    from (
        select 
         ADDRESS:City :: varchar City
        ,ADDRESS:Country :: varchar Country
        ,ADDRESS:County :: varchar County
        ,ADDRESS:Line1 :: varchar Line1
        ,ADDRESS:PostalCode :: varchar PostalCode
        ,ADDRESS:Region :: varchar Region
        from q5
    )
)
;
```